# Does this Gaussian integration converge?

Tags: real-analysis, statistics, probability-distributions

for $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dx \, \frac{1}{x + \mu} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$.  Does it converge? Or at what condition of $\mu$ does it converge? If it converges, what is the result? $\frac{1}{x + \mu}$ seems to cancel each other on the two side of line $x = -\mu$, so the integration seems to converge, at least when $\mu$ is sufficiently large.

Comment: there are 3 places you have to explore integrability -- at $x \to \pm \infty$ and $x \to -\mu$...

Comment: The integration is obviously 0 when $\mu = 0$.  The result seems close to $\frac{1}{\mu}$ when $\mu >> 1$.

Comment: It blows up like $1/x$ near $x = - \mu$, which is not (locally) integrable near it's singularity, so that the integral must diverge (assuming $\mu$ real).

Comment: The two side of $\frac{1}{x + \mu}$ near $x=-\mu$ seems to cancel each other using Taylor expansion.  When $\mu >> 1$, $e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$ becomes flat.  In extreme case, $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dx \frac{1}{x} = 0$.

Comment: The integral is divergent in the usual sense, so you'll need to consider the [Cauchy principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value). See [Hilbert transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform), and in particular the [Dawson function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawson_function), which (up to a constant) is the Hilbert transform of the Gaussian.

Answer (score 2):

Contrast these two things:
\begin{align}
& \lim_{\varepsilon\,\downarrow\,0} \left( \int_{-\infty}^{-\mu-\varepsilon} + \int_{-\mu+\varepsilon}^{+\infty} \right) \frac 1 {x+\mu} e^{-x^2/2} \, dx \\[8pt]
& \lim_{\varepsilon\,\downarrow\,0} \left( \int_{-\infty}^{-\mu-\varepsilon} + \int_{-\mu+2\varepsilon}^{+\infty} \right) \frac 1 {x+\mu} e^{-x^2/2} \, dx
\end{align}
The only difference is that one of them has $-\mu+2\varepsilon$ where the other has $-\mu+\varepsilon.$ But the limits differ from each other. That can happen because we have
\begin{align}
& \lim_{\varepsilon\,\downarrow\,0} \int_{-\infty}^{-\mu-\varepsilon} \frac 1 {x+\mu} e^{-x^2/2} \, dx = -\infty \\[8pt]
\text{and } & \lim_{\varepsilon\,\downarrow\,0} \int^{+\infty}_{-\mu+\varepsilon} \frac 1 {x+\mu} e^{-x^2/2} \, dx = +\infty.
\end{align}
If both of the latter limits were finite, then the difference between the first two limits above would be zero.

(The first limit about is the "principal value" of $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac 1 {x+\mu} e^{-x^2/2} \, dx.$)

Here's a simpler case:
$$
\lim_{\varepsilon\,\downarrow\,0} \left( \int_{-1}^{-\varepsilon} + \int_{2\varepsilon}^1 \right) \frac {dx} x = -\log_e 2.
$$